# Panda dataframe overwrite the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to retrieve data for each device from website through api, and saving all data for each associated dev in one csv file

but there's something wrong with the loop I written that it overwrites the information and only show one row output

(even though when I try to print it to see the output, it shows all records! but for some reason doesn't store these records)

this is my try below

```
for col_name, data in all_device_ids.items():
data # single device id at a time (colums for all_device_ids is "id" only)
for devid in data: # looping on all device ids to make a request for each of them
    try: 
        request = requests.get("https://confidential.com/event/events?type=LocationUpdate&source="+devid+"&withSourceAssets=true&withSourceDevices=true&dateFrom=2021-07-17T00:00:00.00Z&dateTo=2021-07-18T00:00:00.00Z&pageSize=1&currentPage=1", auth=(user,passwd),headers=headers).json()
        df_nested_list = pd.json_normalize(request, record_path =['events'])
        full = df_nested_list.dropna(axis=1)
        full.columns
        focus = full[["id","creationTime","type"]]
        focus
        #print(focus)
        focus.to_csv('eventsdata.csv', index=False,encoding="utf-8-sig") 
#dropped = focus.drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')

    except:
        'no events for this device'
```

output would be a single row only!! it updates/overwrite the value when each request is posted in the loop

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to save all outputs in 1 csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the default setting of "mode" used in the "to_csv" method.
The mode is set to "w" by default. In your case we should be appending, so it should be explicitly set to "a"

```
focus.to_csv('eventsdata.csv', index=False,encoding="utf-8-sig",mode='a')
```

Comment: Thank you!! this worked. it adds also the columns titles each time for each record - is it possible to only append the data without the columns? or delete the entire row for the rows that starts with text "id" for example

Comment: You can use header = False to turnoff writing headers. But if header has to be there in the first row then may be use a counter and if counter = 1 : header_flag=True else header_flag = False and pass the flag to header argument in to_csv.